# rearrange a xref / csv by column 1 and header row

Tags: python, linux, bash, csv

Hopefully someone may have come across this kind of thing before.... I have a csv file on a Linux server that I need to 'massage' into a format that I can use as a lookup table in another product. The current file format does not lend itself well to this other product so I was hoping to rearrange the data into something I can use.

I have tried using a bash script without too much success ( mostly performance) but I suspect, with the very limited knowledge that I have with the language, Python would be a better candidate.

The current file I have has a header row and the first column is the date i.e.

```
Date,USD,JPY,BGN,CYP,
2017-04-28,1.093,121.76,1.9558,26.922,
2017-04-27,1.0881,121.27,1.9558,26.937,
```

( this is a much simplified example! In reality, there are 43 columns and 4,600 rows )

My goal is to create an output file which would look like...

```
Date, Currency, FX_Rate
2017-04-28, USD, 1.093
2017-04-28, JPY, 121.76
2017-04-28, BGN, 1.9558
2017-04-28, CYP, 26.922
2017-04-27, USD, 1.0881
2017-04-27, JPY, 121.27
2017-04-27, BGN, 1.9558
2017-04-27, CYP, 26.937
```

(the space are irrelevant - I just added them to try and make it clearer)

Thanks for any help offered,

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using Python's built in `csv` library. The following will work on a Python 2.x installation.

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(["Date", "Currency", "FX_Rate"])

    for row in csv_input:
        date = row[0]

        for index, currency in enumerate(row[1:], start=1):
            csv_output.writerow([date, header[index], currency])
```

Giving you:

```
Date,Currency,FX_Rate
2017-04-28,USD,1.093
2017-04-28,JPY,121.76
2017-04-28,BGN,1.9558
2017-04-28,CYP,26.922
2017-04-27,USD,1.0881
2017-04-27,JPY,121.27
2017-04-27,BGN,1.9558
2017-04-27,CYP,26.937
```

If Python 3 is being used, you will need to change as follows:

```
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
```